# KNeighborsClassifier not reading in knn__n_neighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

[image]

[image]

I have tried explicitly specify the param_grid but its not behaving and all the tutorials say this is the way its done and I have done it like this before but it wont work this time

Comment: Please paste code rather than including images (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 2):

The estimator you are passing to `GridSearchCV` is a `KNeighborsClassifier`, so the parameter name you should use in the parameter grid is the same you would have passed to the classifier, i.e., `n_neighbors`.

The double underscore notation `<name>__<parameter_name>` you are using is needed when your estimator is part of a [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html): in this case, `<name>` must be the name of the step in the pipeline where the estimator is called.

For example, if you have a pipeline such as

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier())])
```

then the exact parameter grid you used can be passed to the grid search like this:

```
cv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=rkf, scorer=scorer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was mixing Regression with classifiers so I needed to change my KnnClasifier to KnnRegressor and my scorer to mean_squered_error